# API Gateway Latency Issue While Connecting to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My lambda function works less than 1300 MS when I click the test button on the Lambda Page. (Lambda Page: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=eu-central-1#/functions/myfunc?tab=graph)

When I send a request to Lambda via API Gateway then I have to wait for 4300 ms.

The HTTP requests, which goes to Lambda via Gateway work 3-4 times slow.

I saw some similar forum posts. However, I couldn't find a solution for this issue.

How can I reduce the latency?

Comment: Just so you know, nobody can see your graphs.  If you need to publish them, the easiest way is probably to screenshot them and host them on imgur or something similar.

Comment: I know that. I shared the url if someone thinks "where is the test button?"

Comment: This seems excessive... but do you see the same increase on multiple, sequential requests?

Answer (score -1):

API Gateway is known to introduce a lot of latency.

Lambda is not ideal for synchronous requests + responses as you seem to be using it.  It's more suited to asynchronous processes where the latency between invocation and execution are not as critical.

You should probably think about whether your system needs to be synchronous, and if it needs to be synchronous whether lambda is the best answer.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been downvoted, as this is the reality of using API Gateway (unless the latency situation has been resolved in the past two years, which does not seem to have occurred). The round-trip time versus even micro EC2 instances is easily 1.5-2x.